# Scanf is ignored

Tags: c, scanf

I have an assignment in which I have to input dimensions of the first matrix, then which operation i would like to perform('-', '+' or '*'; subtraction, addition and multiplying respectively), and after that dimensions of the second matrix. But after entering first dimensions, I receive error message related to char. I cannot figure it out, even after reading a lot about whitespaces and errors related to scanf. Please help. Thank you

```
int main(void){

    int rows_1 = 0, columns_1 = 0;                  //MATRIX_1 DIM
    int rows_2 = 0, columns_2 = 0;                  //MATRIX_2 DIM
    char c = ' ';
    
    if(scanf("%d %d", &rows_1, &columns_1)!=2)       //input first size
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        return 100;
    }

    scanf("%c", &c);
    
    if( c!='*' || c!='-' || c!='+' )                //error handling for char
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        return 100;  
    }
    
    if(scanf("%d%d", &rows_2, &columns_2)!=2)       //input second size
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        return 100;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* problems:

1. The first is that `c` will contain the *newline* you pressed after the input for `rows_1` and `columns_1`. Add a single leading space in the format string: `" %c"` to skip leading white-space (like newlines).
2. The second issue is that the logical condition is wrong and will always be `true`, no matter the input for `c`.

   You probably want the opposite of `c=='*' || c=='-' || c=='+'`, which according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is `c!='*' && c!='-' && c!='+'` (but you can also use the logical negation operator `!` as in `!(c=='*' || c=='-' || c=='+')`).

   This is rather easy to figure out if you think about it for a little. Lets say that `c` is a newline `'\n'`. Then `c!='*'` is *true* and due to the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the logical operators, the remaining condition will not be evaluated. The same happens for any other character, including the ones you check for (exchange the newline for e.g. `'-'` and `c!='*'` will still be true; also try with `'*'` and then `c!='*'` will be false but `c!='-'` will be true).